# Parameter expansion slow for large data sets

Tags: bash

If I take the first 1,000 bytes from a file, Bash can replace some characters pretty quick

```
$ cut -b-1000 get_video_info
muted=0&status=ok&length_seconds=24&endscreen_module=http%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2F
yts%2Fswfbin%2Fendscreen-vfl4_CAIR.swf&plid=AATWGZfL-Ysy64Mp&sendtmp=1&view_coun
t=3587&author=hye+jeong+Jeong&pltype=contentugc&threed_layout=1&storyboard_spec=
http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fsb%2FLHelEIJVxiE%2Fstoryboard3_L%24L%2F%24N.jpg%7C48
%2327%23100%2310%2310%230%23default%23cTWfBXjxZMDvzL5cyCgHdDJ3s_A%7C80%2345%2324
%2310%2310%231000%23M%24M%23m1lhUvkKk6sTnuyKXnPBojTIqeM%7C160%2390%2324%235%235%
231000%23M%24M%23r-fWFZpjrP1oq2uq_Y_1im4iu2I%7C320%23180%2324%233%233%231000%23M
%24M%23uGg7bth0q6XSYb8odKLRqkNe7ao&approx_threed_layout=1&allow_embed=1&allow_ra
tings=1&url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=fallback_host%3Dtc.v11.cache2.c.youtube.com%2
6quality%3Dhd1080%26sig%3D610EACBDE06623717B1DC2265696B473C47BD28F.98097DEC78411
95A074D6D6EBFF8B277F9C071AE%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr9---sn-q4f7dney.c.youtub
e.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fms%253Dau%2526ratebypass%253Dyes%2526ipbits%253D8%25
26key%253Dyt1%2526ip%253D99.109.97.214%2

$ read aa < <(cut -b-1000 get_video_info)

$ time set "${aa//%/\x}"

real    0m0.025s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.000s
```

However if I take 10,000 bytes it slows dramatically

```
$ read aa < <(cut -b-10000 get_video_info)

$ time set "${aa//%/\x}"

real    0m8.125s
user    0m8.127s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I read [Greg Wooledge’s post](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021) but it lacks an explanation as to why Bash parameter expansion is slow.

Comment: `bash` was never designed for bulk data processing; it's a glue language for running other commands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the *why*, you can see the implementation of this code in `pat_subst` in `subst.c` in the bash source code.

For each match in the string, the length of the string is counted numerous times (in `pat_subst`, `match_pattern` and `match_upattern`), both as a C string and more expensively as a multibyte string. This makes the function both slower than necessary, and more importantly, quadratic in complexity.

This is why it's slow for larger input, and here's a pretty graph:

[image: Quadratic runtime in shell replacements]

As for workarounds, just use `sed`. It's more likely to be optimized for string replacement operations (though you should be aware that POSIX only guarantees 8192 bytes per line, even though GNU sed handles arbitrarily large ones).

Answer (score 1):

Originally, older shells and other utilities imposed LINE_MAX = 2048 
on file input for this kind of reason.  For huge variables bash has no 
problem parking them in memory. But substitution requires at least two 
concurrent copies. And lots of thrashing: as groups of characters are 
removed whole strings get rewritten.  Over and over and over.

There are tools meant for this - sed is a premiere choice.  bash is a 
distant second choice.  sed works on streams, bash works on memory blocks.

Another choice:
bash is extensible - your can write custom C code to stuff stuff well 
when bash was not meant to do it.

CFA Johnson has good articles on how to do that:

Some ready to load builtins:

http://cfajohnson.com/shell/bash/loadables/

DIY builtins explained:

http://cfajohnson.com/shell/articles/dynamically-loadable/