# Nested parameter substitution in POSIX shell

Tags: posix, sh

Nesting parameter substitutions works in Zsh:

```
$ param=abc

# nested remove prefix ${...#a} and remove suffix ${...%c} =>
$ printf '%s\n' ${${param#a}%c}
# => b
```

Is there any equivalent in POSIX?

```
$ param=abc
$ printf '%s\n' ${${param#a}%c}
# => dash: 2: Bad substitution
# => sh: ${${param#a}%c}: bad substitution
# => bash: ${${param#a}%c}: bad substitution
```

Comment: No, there is no equivalent in POSIX. Is running one substitution per command really such a pain?

Comment: Not practically, no, but it really bugs my design sense to use multiple commands due to needing an intermediate value.

Comment: Those are not "commands". The "A=B" types of expressions evaluated completely inside the shell and pose negligible performance penalty, if that what you are concerned about. As Charles said, POSIX' Bourne shell simply doesn't support it and it is unlikely that it would ever will. I generally use either temp intermediate variables or `eval`, depending on what I need.

Comment: They're "commands" in the "simple command" sense of the [POSIX shell spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).  I'm not worried about performance.  I'm worried about programmer happiness and aesthetics.  Though, worrying about POSIX compatibility is basically throwing in the towel on programmer happiness.  Mostly surprised it didn't work in `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `expr` instead to extract the text between the desired prefix and suffix. (This is not, of course, a general purpose equivalent to nested expressions, but does solve your given problem.)

```
param=abc
expr "$param" : "a\(.*\)c"
```

The regular expression matching operator `:` of `expr` takes two arguments: the left argument is a string, the right argument is a regular expression. The output is whatever is matched inside the `\(...\)` group.

Comment: Nice! I often forget about `expr`, and I didn't know it had capturing groups.

Comment: Well, group (singular) anyway :) With more than one group, you only get the output of the first one.

Comment: keep in mind that the regex for expr's `:` operator is implicitly anchored at the start of the string (i.e. `"^a\(.*\)c"`), so the regex will *not* match the string "1abc"

Comment: I've never understood why that limitation exists. Efficiency, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Bash does not, but you have a host of other tools that can get the job done.

```
cut -b2 <<< abc
tr -d ac <<< abc
sed s/[ac]// <<< abc
awk '$0=$2' FS= <<< abc
```

It should be noted that parameter substitution does not scale

[Parameter expansion slow for large data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14967299)

Comment: printf '4 %s\n' $( ( sed 's/^a\(.*\)c$/\1/' <<< $param ) )